# how to save Canvas as image in WINRT using c#

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [saving canvas as image in metro style app with C#/XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11239980/saving-canvas-as-image-in-metro-style-app-with-c-xaml)

Can anyone please guide me how to save canvas as Image in Windows store app using C#.

If this is not possible then any alternate way or workaround for this ?

I have searched a lot on this but not getting any.

Any help will be grateful.